# Does Fortnite Account Merge Reset Stats?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I'm sure some of you may be aware that Fortnite has FINALLY given us a way to merge our accounts. However, I wish to know if our stats will be reset in the event I create a new Username/Account and merge it with my previous one. I know all cosmetics etc will be moved to my new account but will my stats reflect there too?

Answer (score 1):

According to this [source](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/account-merge-delay?sessionInvalidated=true) (except the part that is a mention about the delay)

> In November, we’re going to release an “account merging” system so you can combine multiple console-linked accounts to transfer Battle Royale cosmetic item purchases, **lifetime wins**, V-Bucks, and Save the World campaign access.

So stats will be transferred => merged.

Other source mention game stats will be [merged](https://www.cultofmac.com/581192/epic-fortnite-merge-multiple-accounts/).

Comment: although useful, the current [Account Merge Page from Epic](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/account-merge/en-US/home) says nothing about stats.

Answer (score 0):

I have a friend who plays on mobile and Xbox, he was able to get his skins through, but sadly his stats did not merge.